# Wordpress Conditional Add Secondary Role

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a function that works like this one of these:

Is primary user role Subscriber but NOT also any other secondary role? Then add the secondary role "Staff" to the user. So they are Subscriber & Staff.

I suck with conditional PHP. Can anyone give me a clean function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of User Role plugins out there that could help, such as [Multiple Roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-roles/). I've personally not used it so I can't attest to how well it performs. If you just want a simple function, you will need to make use of the [`add_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) function on a [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object.

So, get your User Object however you want:

- If you want to do this to the currently logged in user, use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/).
- If you want to do this by user ID, you can use [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/).
- If you want to do this by another user field (username, email, etc. *note: ID works here too*) use [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

To run this for any user that's logged in, you can use something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_staff_role_to_subscriber');
function add_staff_role_to_subscriber(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        // If user is a Subscriber with NO other roles
        if( $user->roles[0] == 'subscriber' && ! isset( $user->roles[1] ) ){
            $user->add_role('staff');
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is make sure the current user is logged in, and then gets the `WP_User` object for that user. `$user->roles` is a single-dimensional array, so you can just make sure that the only role assigned to them is `subscriber` and that there is no second `$role` in the array by making sure `$user->roles[1]` isn't set, or is false.

Once the `staff` role is added to the user, the if statement will always be false since `$user->roles[1]` will be set to `staff`, or if they already have a secondary role it won't effect them.

Note, that in your question you have `Subscriber` capitalized, but roles are lowercase in WordPress, so I made `staff` lowercase in my code. You may need to make sure the capitalization matches before executing this code.

Comment: Thank you Xhynk. Super as always. One question - why make it conditional on the user being logged in? Is that essentially a trigger that gets the function to run, because it needs an event of some kind to make the function run?

Comment: Because otherwise `wp_get_current_user()` will return a `WP_User` object with an id of 0. Since you'd only want this on valid users anyways, you might as well make sure they're logged in - it will effectively just skip the function if they aren't logged in, which saves a (minuscule) amount of performance, checking the other `if` statement. Just a decent practice to make sure a user is logged in before doing things on logged in users

Comment: If you'd rather loop through all the users, you can use the [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) function and sort of do it in bulk as well

Comment: This is superb wisdom. I can't tell you how many inefficient code snippets I've seen that query a whole database (sometimes continuously in a loop) to perform a simple change. Stand by for another cup of coffee from a grateful recipient. Truly, thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad to help! Also note that I suggested doing it for the logged in user, because if you do it in bulk with something like `get_users()`, you'll need to also keep checking when new subscribers are added. In either case, if you need to add it directly when new subscribers are added, you can look at [This Tutorial](https://www.role-editor.com/add-secondary-role-new-registered-user/) for ideas

Comment: Above function should trigger when user has only subscriber role. User who becomes "subscriber" but doesn't complete registration for secondary role gets lowest level of 2ndary role ("contributor" - changed from staff). Problem is someone switched 2ndary role from colleague to member & system re-added colleague as a second *primary* role. They became subscriber,colleague+member. It's the function because site adds colleague or member as 2ndary role, with subscriber as the primary. When she switched 2ndary role from colleague to member, function added colleague as another primary role.

Comment: So it sounds like once the custom role is added, if the first role is changed they should lose the secondary one? I updated the code to include an else statement that removes the role if they're not a `subscriber` by using the [`remove_role()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_role) function: `$user->remove_role('staff');`. Is that what it needs to do?

Comment: The existing member system automatically removes one secondary role to replace it with another secondary role. So I don't think the function needs to do it too. I'm not sure how the original secondary role got added back into the mix, but let me look farther into it. I'm testing now.

Comment: Hey I solved the issue. Thanks for weighing in. Nothing wrong with the function at all, actually. It's an incorrect trigger in the membership system. In fact, your original function allows me to turn off the extra trigger and all works as it should. More coffee coming your way. Thank you Xhynk!

Comment: Could you set the function back to way it was above?

Comment: Thank you! And sure thing - I've set it back to the previous version (if you _do_ ever need to look back at it, you can click the [`edited (x time) ago`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51622912/revisions) link to see all revisions, if you do ever need to remove added roles based on another role at least